# Entity Framework Core leaving many connections in sleeping status

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, kubernetes, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core API using Entity Framework Core. The DB context is registered in startup.cs like this:

```
  services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
         providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60)));
```

In connection string I set

```
  Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Timeout=300
```

The controller calls methods in a service which in turn makes calls to aysnc methods in a repo for data retrieval and processing.

All worked well if concurrent user is under 500 during load testing. However beyond that number I start to see a lot of timeout expired errors. When I checked the database, there's no deadlock but I could see well over 100 connections in sleeping mode(the API is hosted on two kubernetes pods). I monitored these connections during the testing and it appeared that instead of current sleeping connections being reused, new ones were added to the pool. My understanding is entity framework core manages opening and closing connections but this didn't seem to be the case. Or am I missing anything?

> The error looks like this:
>
> `StatusCode":500,"Message":"Error:Timeout expired`.  The timeout period
> elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have
> occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size
> was reached. Stack Trace:

at

> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection)\n

at

> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\n   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)\n   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides
> overrides)\n

at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\n   at

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean
> errorsExpected)\n

at

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean
> errorsExpected)\n   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
> isolationLevel)\n.....................

An example of how the `dbcontext` was used:

the controller calls a method in a service class:

```
  var result = await _myservice.SaveUserStatusAsync(userId, status);
```

then in `'myservice'`:

```
  var user = await _userRepo.GetUserAsync(userId);

  ....set user status to new value and then

  return await _userRepo.UpdateUserAsync(user);
```

then in `'userrepo'`:

```
  _context.user.Update(user);
   var updated = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return updated > 0;
```

Update:

Thanks very much to Ivan Yang who generously offered the bounty. Although I'm still investigating, I've learned a lot by reading all the comments and answers below. Here is what I've tried so far: I increased the pool size to 200 (I know it's not the right way to deal with the issue), increased the number of pods so that the API now runs on 4 pods and allocated more memory to each pod. The end result so far has been good:500 errors disappear completely with up to 2000 concurrent users. I will update this question with my findings after I try other options.

Comment: How many connection pools are involved? Note that max 100 connections is the default for one pool. Also, why are the timeouts that high? It indicates that you have processes that are heavier than you can afford with that number of users.

Comment: @GertArnold  There's only one connection string so it's one pool. The API is hosted in Kubernetes and there're two pods and requests are made from both pods, each with 1 pool. The queries are mostly select, although table joints are involved(there're a few queries that involve 'include')  There's no deadlock found when timeout occurred though. Also I'm confused about why the connections are not being reused. They are just sitting there 'sleeping'.

Comment: Describe more the process you went through to come to the conclusions you did

Comment: @CaiusJard I ran queries to view connections on sql server during the load testing and saw over 100 connections sleeping (connection pool size was 100 but the API was 'hosted' on two pods).

Comment: And what were you expecting to see?

Comment: @CaiusJard Not that many sleeping connections maybe? Instead of new connections being added to handle queries, shouldn't existing ones be reused? What am I supposed to see in your opinion?

Comment: Well, the max pool size is apparently working.. I wouldn't be at all surprised if, upon startup, 100 connections were created and then (if the app was very quiet) many of them were never used.. I get the feeling that you're expecting it to work like "even at the busiest my app should never need more than 5 simult connections active, so I should see 5 sleeping. If it did get so busy that all 5 were in use then a 6th would be added if a new request came in.." ? Consider that aggressively keeping the number of active connections to the min needed would cause slowdown for creating new ones ad hoc

Comment: @CaiusJard i see what you meant. but I actually got timeout expired, while so many connections were sleeping.

Comment: What kind of timeouts: connection or command timeouts? Note that commands may always timeout even when 100 connections are sleeping.

Comment: How do you use that AppDBContext in your code? Can you give an example?

Comment: @GertArnold I think it's connection timeout. I've updated the question with error details.

Comment: @AndrewSilver I've updated my question with an example of how dbcontext was used.

Comment: Make sure your DbContext is correctly being disposed. You are registering your repository instances with DI like `services.addScoped<YourRepository>()`, right? If after some exception under load test the DBContext is not disposed then this may be the root issue of leaking connections.

Comment: @AndrewSilver, yes, the repo was correctly registered like this:   services.AddScoped<IUserRepo,UserRepo>()

Comment: Could you share code inside ``_userRepo.GetUserAsync(userId);``? is there any subquery in this method?

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but we can see on their samples -> Miscellaneous -> ConfiguringDbContext -> WithContextFactory the _contextFactory.CreateDbContext() it will be resposible to dispose the context and not the DI, and on the example has a using so I deduce that at the end it will call the dispose of the DbContext AKA killing the connection. The samples are available at https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Something like this:   var result =await _context.Users.Where(i => i.IsActive==1 && ((userId != 0 && i.userd == userId)||(userId==0 && 1==1)))
                 .Include(i => i.UserTests)
                 .ToListAsync();

return result;
When userId is 0, return all users with their tests

Comment: In case of userId=0, how many Users and UserTests are in database? Which version of EF Core you use?

Comment: Two servers, 100 connections in two pools and 500 concurrent users in the test. Aren't you just of your physical limits?

Comment: @SamulP `_userRepo.` there's your bug. Using the "generic repository" antipattern.  A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work caching all changes and persisting all of them in a single transaction when you call `SaveChanges`. The code you posted *breaks* this and that `Update` may well execute 42 DELETEs. Worse, to get back the UoW functionality you now need an **explicit transaction** which requires a **long lived open connection** and hence - leaks, blocks and deadlocks

Comment: @SamulP DbContext *doesn't* leave connections open unless you explicitly force it to by starting a database transaction. It's explicitly designed to open connections only to load data or persist cached changes and closes them immediately. A DbContext is a high-level multi-entity Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is a single-entity Repository. By putting that low-level, single entity "generic repository" on top of them you broke both and caused the problems you encountered. I put `"generic repository"` in quotes because it's actually a CRUD Data-Access-Object, not a repo

Comment: Are you using transactionscope somewhere? Do you have any background services or worker jobs?

Comment: @WiktorZychla concurrent users doesn't mean concurrent connections and even if it did, 500 is a *small* number if connections are used correctly. The OP's code though is a very common form of **bad** usage. It uses a "generic repository" and calls `SaveChanges` on every single update. It's almost certain the code that wasn't posted uses explicit transactions, keeps connections open leading to blocking and timeouts.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the OP specifically means "concurrent users during load testing", not just "500 users". Combining this with their unusually high command timeout, this could probably mean that there are some heavy queries executed. And now, try 500 concurrent long lasting queries on a 200 combined pools and you have their *The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached*.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I said concurrent users too. 500 concurrent HTTP requests doesn't mean 500 database connections and pooling ensures that far fewer connections would be used *unless the code itself was buggy*. Even with 500 concurrent queries, there's no reason to take too long *unless the code causes blocking*. Why would a single row read or update take 60 seconds? Because the code itself caused locking for an extended time, by using a database transaction either explicitly with `BeginTransaction` or implicitly with a `TransactionScope`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: we have no idea what the actual code does. We only have **an example**. Without detailed knowledge of what actual queries cause the issue and how load tests are performed (note their load tests could doesn't even involve http!), it's only guessing. My guess is that they can exhaust the limit of what this physical infrastructure is capable of. For some reason, you try to convince me I am wrong. Not sure what for.

Comment: @WiktorZychla but we do, from the description and the symptoms. I've answered hundreds of identical questions over the decades. Reads don't block each other. Long-lived *transactions* that mix reads and updates do. And the "repo/DAO over ORM" **anti**pattern is behind almost every single blocking issue when it comes to ORMs. This is nothing new, the problems of this antipattern are known for over 10 years. The code fails after *5 minutes for a single update*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: reads don't block but you still need a connection in the pool. Despite my own 25 years experiece, I am not that confident and based on vague details I would not draw decisive conclusions that easily. But I respect your approach. Regards.

Comment: @WiktorZychla same experience, SQL Server MVP in 2005, and actually fixed blocks, improved throughput 1000 times by *preventing* long-lived transactions in high-traffic systems. I actually remember the huge perf improvement brought by disconnected recordsets. It's extremely disappointing that we need to fix the exact same problems 20 years later. Except now people forgot how databases work making it a lot harder to convince them

Comment: @WiktorZychla in fact, restricting the pool size **increases** throughput by reducing blocking. That's not an "in my experience" either, throttling is fundamental in all service-based systems. In fact, all TPC benchmark submissions used COM+ as a transaction-processing monitor to *throttle* concurrent connections. The OP may get better results by *reducing* the max pool size. A 500-way block is a lot harder to fix than a 40-way block

Comment: @SamulP consider *lowering* the max pool size. Right now your code is causing a 500-way block. If you *reduce* the number of concurrent transactions the existing ones will be able to finish a lot faster. That's why services throttle the number of allowed concurrent requests.

Comment: @SamulP: *but I could see well over 100 connections in sleeping mode* the critical question here is: do you also see these sleeping/stalled connections in your tests when less than 500 concurrent requests are used in testing?

Comment: Did you check, that starting from 0 with every new call a new connection is added? Maybe you have problems with your DI and you are creating new DbContexts with each call which are not reused or disposed. Then every new DbContext would add a new connection which stays forever. Hard to analyze without more code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Really appreciate your input. I'm new to EF Core and still have a lot to learn but were you saying I shouldn't use my custom repo and instead should use dbcontext directly? I understand that when I call SaveChanges', all pending changes will be saved. However when user calls the update endpoint, that endpoint calls relevant service method which in turn calls the repo method that does nothing else but selecting and updating one record. In this case calling savechanges every time the update endpoint is called shouldn't have any negative impact right?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Really appreciate your input too! I tried simulating load testing by running a curl script on my local machine (so the connection pool was 100) and noticed the sleeping connections started to appear even when the concurrent users were below 100.

Comment: @SamulP please post the missing code. Don't force us to guess. As for negative impact, yes, there's a severe negative impact. Instead of making 1 call you make 100. You have no way of cancelling those changes, which means you now have to use an explicit transaction. That in turn means keeping the connection open. Besides, EF already tracks changes, and will only persist the values that changed. That `Update` is useless if you work with objects loaded by EF Core itself. When you use `Update` with an untracked entity, EF assumes *every* property is modified so it saves everything

Comment: @SamulP as using DbContext directly, that `_myService` seems to act like the actual repo - the actual class that manages and abstracts storage. You already have a storage abstraction. All `_myservice.SaveUserStatusAsync` needs to do is `var user=_context.Users.Find(userId); user.Status=status; _context.SaveChanges();`. No need to check the count - if the user is missing you'll get an exception.If another request modifies the same user before you save you'll get an optimistic concurrency exception. You can delay calling `SaveChanges` until the end of the request to persist all changes at once

Comment: @SamulP: could you post an example snippet of your repository. In particular, how's the dbcontext injected into the repository (which would be correct)? Or maybe it isn't and a new context is created by the repository (which would be incorrect)?

Answer (score 11):

> Error:Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
> connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
> connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

This is almost always a connection leak.  And here the fact that your queries are short-running, and you see idle connections on the server confirms it.  Somewhere you're leaving an open connection.

A DbContext will open/close the underlying connection, and return it to the pool on Dispose.  But if you start a transaction on a connection and don't commit or rollback, the connection will be segregated in the pool and won't be reused.  Or if you return an `IEnumerable` or a `DataReader` that never gets iterated and disposed, the connection can't be reused.

Look at the "sleeping" sessions to see what their last query was, and cross-reference that with your code to track down the call site that leaked the connection.  First try the DMVs, eg

```
select s.session_id, s.open_transaction_count, ib.event_info
from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(s.session_id,null) ib
```

Or start an Extended Events trace if necessary.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Could you clarify what you mean about returning IEnumerable and how it's related to disposing DBContext?

Comment: @AndrewSilver this answer talks about the connection, not DbContext. The OP's problem is caused because connections aren't closed, thus keeping any acquired locks. The anti-pattern used in the OP's code causes connections to remain open until a DbContext is disposed, instead of letting DbContext close them as soon as possible

Comment: @AndrewSilver: this answer seem to assume that contexts (and thus connections) are created somewhere else, not only by injecting/disposing automatically by the runtime's DI. However, assuming the context is only injected into the controller (and then from the controller to the repository), there's no way of it being improperly disposed. And the OP specifically mentions in the comments that their repo is scoped (their db context also is).

Comment: And yet, they are leaking connections.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks! I did check the last queries of the sleeping sessions and they were almost all select (more specifically select top 1) queries, with a few update queries on the same table. I also made sure all the queries ended with tolistasync or firstordefaultasync.

Answer (score 2):

connection leaks cause such problems, connections probably is not getting closed properly unless Garbage collector is used to trash all those dangling connections using `IDisposable`, finally clause can be added to ensure that connections are closed after its use.

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/legacy/aa175863(v=sql.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is helpful to understand this issue.

As far as entity framework concerned, max pool size can be achieved by keeping many object in database context, while you can materialize them using `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList` functions, as queries can hold connections to database server

Comment: thanks. i did check to make sure all the queries ended with tolistasync or firstordefaultasync.

Comment: *FirstOrDefault or ToList functions (...) can hold connections* -- I'm sorry? Any references to back that claim? As for "leaking connections", EF always closes connections after any database interaction. In fact, it's not even necessary to Dispose contexts.

Comment: I think he means that _not_ using `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList` can hold onto queries, ie if you partially enumerate an IQueryable, it holds the connection open.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `DbContext` implements `IDisposable`.

Best practice (for many reasons, not just connection management) is to new up your `DbContext` in a using statement:

```
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    // do your work
}
```

I wrote a [small library](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient) that assists you in implementing and enforcing a pattern such as this.

Comment: It's not how you use the EF in aspnet core.

Comment: It is exactly how you use the EF in aspnet core.

Comment: Usually in EF.Core you use either DBContext initialized though DI or DbContextFactory. So  approach mentioned above is not very common, I believe.

Comment: @Sam: There are multiple ways, some involve automatically injecting the context instance to controllers by the DI container, some involve passing a context options or a connection string into the context. Your suggestion to always create the context by hand is not always applicable.

Comment: @AndrewSilver on the contrary, it's extremely common. EF existed long before the current DI frameworks by Microsoft and doesn't depend on them *at all*. The DI is simply irrelevant. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work so it *has* to be created as late as possible and disposed right after use. In fact, that "generic" repository **anti**pattern causes leaks by breaking this pattern, requiring the use of explicit database transactions, long-lived connections. Exactly what the OP's problem is

Comment: @WiktorZychla that's wrong. All those ways do what this question does - create a DbContext instance as late as possible and dispose it immediately after use. There's no need for an extra library for this. Even when you use DI you're using the same pattern. And one of the main problems introduced by the "generic repository" antipattern is that it *breaks* this pattern, requiring explicit transactions and ... leaks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: you are completely missing the point of these comments. The point is, when the EF core context is automatically injected by the DI into the controller, it is also automatically disposed by the runtime at the end of the request (the `AddDbContext` the OP uses registers the ef context as **scoped**). Thus, an answer that replaces one legitimate way of disposing the context (automatically disposing injected context by the runtime at the end of the request) with another way of disposing the context (by wrapping it with `using`) will probably not resolve OP's issue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Also, the generic repository is not an antipattern on itself. If there's a repository that has the dbcontext injected into it so that the dbcontext lifetime is controlled externally, not by the repository but by another entity and - by chance - this external entity is the asp.net runtime with scoped contexts that are automatically created and disposed per request, then nothing is broken. This important detail, how repositories are implemented is missing here. But, you somehow assume that their implementation is wrong. Is this just your presentiment or there is any evidence?

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes it is. Because the DbSet is the repository. The DbContext is the UoW. That's why that "generic repo" (it's actually a DAO) is putting a lower-level abstraction over a high-level abstraction. And the question's code is the proof - an `UpdateUserAsync` that calls a useless `_context.user.Update` followed by a `SaveChanges`. EF Core already tracks entities, what's the point of that `Update`? Unless someone used `AsNoTracking()` "just in case" ?

Comment: @WiktorZychla now for the detailed description of the antipattern. [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) and [The evils of the Repository abstraction layer](https://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer). Oren Eini (Ayende) was the maintainer of NHibernate at the time and the guy ever .NET MVP and author learned ORMs *from*. [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) is more recent

Comment: @WiktorZychla when you already have a full-featured ORM , you don't need a *generic* repository. That's the ORM's job. To raise the abstraction level you need a *specialized* repository suitable to the use case at hand. In DDD layers you'd say a DbContext holds the entities used in a bounded context, nothing more or less.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: their style, mixing repositories and direct context access could be the culprit but considering there's no actual code to review, I still believe there are multiple possible causes.

Comment: @WiktorZychla there are many, many reasons to enclose business logic in a service aka repository layer.  Generic repo is completely wrong it leaks business logic all over the application layer.  Also, DbContext should never be injected or instantiated in a controller.  It is meant to be used in the service layer. Only.  Disposing the DbContext properly is only one of the problems this pattern solves, arguably one of the lesser ones.

Comment: @Sam: there's no reason to avoid injecting the db context and there's nothing to solve, really, as the injected context is properly disposed. Most EF core tutorials recommend this as correct and safe and it sounds like you try to blame all these of being wrong. Also, repository and service is not the same, not sure then what you mean by "service aka repository".

Comment: @WiktorZychla I do not mean to imply DbContext should always be created manually,  In fact if you look at the library I posted it demonstrates how to do this using DI.  Disposing the context properly is always applicable.  The converse statement is saying there are code sections where memory leaks are applicable.

Comment: @Sam: your library could be useful in environments where no DI is easily applicable. But aspnet core already has its container that does injections and controls the lifetime of injected services. Not sure how introducing your library there would improve something that already works.

Comment: > Most EF core tutorials recommend this as correct and safe and it sounds like you try to blame all these of being wrong.  ------ Did you not read the issue posted here approx 8 inches above the comment you are reading now?

Answer (score -4):

Try to turn off the pooling. The pooling trys to keep the connections open. If you turn it off, it uses the provider timeout of 60 seconds you set in the DI

Comment: Do you realize what you're saying?

Comment: Not the downvoter but turning off pooling would kill the performance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with connection pooling. Pooling **prevents** timeouts and delays, it doesn't cause them, because it uses *fewer* connections to serve more requests. `The pooling trys to keep the connections open.` that's almost wrong. Connection pooling *resets* a connection after use and puts it in the pool so it can be reused. Resetting means that any locks are released, transactions rolled back etc. This means that instead of using eg 100 connections to serve 100 requests, the application can use just 2,5 or 10, depending on load.